# php echo query result from 2 different table

Tags: php, sql

**table1**

```
+------+------+
| id   | info |
+------+------+
|  1   |  x   |
|  2   |  y   |
|  3   |  z   |
+------+------+
```

**table2**

```
+--------+------+
| name   | id   |
+--------+------+
|  jhon  |  1   |
| david  |  1   |
| angel  |  2   |
+--------+------+
```

output is :
hello jhon you are x member

there is not possible to merge the colomn it should use 2 different table ( 1 database )

how i can put it on PHP script ?

Comment: Can you clean up your tables?  It is hard to decipher what you are doing/want to do.

Comment: post the output also so we can have a clear picture

Comment: update .... i already edit my question ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to fetch that data then use it as you need -

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.col2 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.status
```

Comment: can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Join Query to get the details
`mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id where t2.name='john'")`